# How to get multiple user inputs and perform calculations basic Calculator

Tags: java

Am trying to create a basic calculator (new to Java). at the moment the user has to enter a number, followed by an operator and then a number. how  can i get all three inputs on a single line?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Calculator 

{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        double numb1, numb2, add, subtract, multiply, divide;   
        char operation;

        while (true)
        {           
            System.out.println("Calculate: ");
            numb1 = in.nextDouble();
            operation = in.next().charAt(0);
            numb2 = in.nextDouble();

            switch(operation)
            {
                case '+':       
                    add = numb1 + numb2;
                    System.out.println(add);
                    break;

                case '-':
                    subtract = numb1 - numb2;
                    System.out.println(subtract);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    multiply = numb1 * numb2;
                    System.out.println(multiply);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    divide = numb1 / numb2;
                    System.out.println(divide);
                    break;
            }

        }   

    }

}
```

Comment: How about scanning the entire equation entered on the command line? If you are only looking for 3 items (for example 1 + 1), then your code is not very portable. What if someone entered "1 + 2 + 3 * 4"? It would be better to parse an entire string, just search for integers and +,-,/,* etc...

Comment: Why just not create simple JFrame with text fields and buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `nextLine()` (returns a `String`), then split it by spaces, and finally convert them to the corresponding types:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double numb1, numb2;
    char operation;

    // Split string by space
    String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

    // Convert to corresponding types
    numb1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    operation = parts[1].charAt(0);
    numb2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);

    ...
}
```

So the input will need to be as:

```
1 + 2
```

with spaces between operators

Comment: this may sound stupid but how would i print out the answer using this method? ^^^

Comment: Using the same you have used.  I mean, the `switch` will be the same, you have to see what you will need to change and what not.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, the calculator - a true classic!

You can ask the `Scanner` class to give you the whole sentence, instead of just *the next number* by calling `nextDouble()`.
You're already doing this in the expression `in.next().charAt(0)`.

However the problem that arises from this is that now you have a whole sentence of text, which is actually a *mathematical term*. How to separate this sentence into a structure that reflects the mathematical term is the work of something called [Parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

That is a non-trivial thing to do in general, but depending on the task you need to do, you'll probably don't need a full blown parser here. If you stick to your example of a single operation on two numbers, you might use a regular expression to extract the information.
For non-negative numbers without decimals, you might use this:

```
Pattern termPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*(\\d*)\\s*([+-*/])\\s*(\\d*)\\s*");
final String sentence = in.next();
Matcher matcher = termPattern.matcher(sentence );
if (!matcher.matches()) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a supported mathematical expression: " + sentence);
}
Integer firstNum = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
Integer secondNum = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(3));
String operation = matcher.group(2);
switch (operation) {
   ...
}
```

I've used Regular Expressions to extract the information from the `String` using the [Java Pattern Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).
However while this is a common thing to do, please note that Regular Expression can't replace a Parser in all cases (and sadly it's tried far too often).

Depending on what you need to do with you Calculator, it might fit the bill.

This solution is still far from beeing perfect, but it supports a range of inputs and is adjustable to some degree. You can easily add negative or decimal values. However if you try to add more complex expressions with `(` and `)` you will reach it's limits. Good luck on exploring!